# php put_file_contents location problems, duplicate files

Tags: php, string, concatenation

The code below fetches a *jpg image* from a server. if the length is larger than 1, we assume to have successfully grabbed the file. Then it proceeds to create a folder for the user if it isnt already there. (this part works)

from there, it should save the file in the `/media/downloads/username` location

instead it is going to `/media/downloads/`

I've looked at my concatenation a few times now, but I don't see where the issue is. I SEE that the filename is coming out with the username attached to the front, so I imagine its just a concatenation error.

Once this is fixed, I have a bigger issue- because I am using rand, when I cycle the script it just gives me duplicates. how can I prevent the duplicate images?!

```
if (strlen($data) > 1) {
     $prePath = 'media/download/from_'.$sender.'_to_'.$recipient.'_id_'.$snapid.'.jpg';
     if (!file_exists('media/download/'.$username)) {
    mkdir('media/download/'.$username, 0777, true);
 }
 if (file_exists($prePath)){
    $finalPath = 'media/download/'.$username.'/from_'.$sender.'_to_'.$recipient.'_id_'.$snapid.rand(0,100).'.jpg';
 }  
 else {
    $finalPath = 'media/download/'.$username.'/from_'.$sender.'_to_'.$recipient.'_id_'.$snapid.rand(0,100).'.jpg';
    }

//echo "<img src='$data'></img>";
file_put_contents($finalPath, $data);
echo  "<a href=".$finalPath."> <img src='".$finalPath."' alt='Smiley face' height='100' width='100'> </a>";

}
```

Comment: yes. thats how somehow $username is getting added to the beginning of the file

Comment: you should use a date or time instead of a random number so you'll never have a duplicate filename.